# IP forwarding server (or other solution)

Tags: ip, vps, web-hosting, dedicated-server

We have physical server based in Hungary that are serving our Hungarian version of a site.
For any other website we launch in different countries,
We buy hosting in that country and launch another website.
The reason for that is that the domain should be tied up to a local IP of the country.
So, for example, we have an SK domain, and we would buy an SK hosting (VPS or dedicated).

I am at a point that i have over 10 of those and maintaining everything has become a difficult task.

So, my question,
Is it possible to have a local IP tied to the domain, but somehow (behind the scenes) the site would be server from our Hungarian server?

Comment: search for CDN, that way you can have all sites served closely to the location of the IP from your user.

Comment: A CDN will serve content files, not ASP.NET site, Or MailServer, FTP Server etc...

Comment: and what makes you think to believe this is not possible to do as well with a similiar setups?

Comment: i think you misunderstand the needs.
A CDN is hosting static files only, it will host .js/.css/.html/images, that is why its called Content Delivery Network.

Comment: example link:
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/11/29/how-content-delivery-networks-cdns-work/
so no, it cannot only server static content, but rather resolves the domain to a close to your resolver location.
Additionally it seems currently example.hk resolves to a hungarian ip and get served by the hungarian server.
Instead you want the example.hk to be resolved to the hungarian IP, but serve everything from another ip possibly.

Comment: Whats your intention in doing so? Liability? Cause you would loose the advantage of local serving speed. And that way you could just let it resolve directly on the main IP.

Comment: Dennis, An Edge server still forces me to have hosting on multiple sites.
I am trying to avoid that, introducing another server to the method im trying to get rid off, is not a solution.
As per your example with example.hk you go it all mixed up.
Our main Server Farm is based in Hungary, any other site (.sk/.co.uk/etc) Should have a Country Local IP attached to them, But get the content ONLY from our Hungarian Farm.
As per the lost of speed, we are only operating in Europe, and it will be marginal (if at all, since most of the pages are static).
as per the Main IP, There is a Google Issue.

Comment: Why do you want a separate IP address for every country? There is no obvious good reason for this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - i do not think that it is related to the question, just part of the requirements.

Comment: It's quite related to the question, since it is at least partly the cause of your problem!

Comment: @Dementic Was my answer able to address your question?  If so, I'd appreciate if you mark it as accepted and/or upvote it so I can get credit for it.  If not, let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon's CloudFront CDN lets you serve dynamic content, and I'd recommend going that route because just because you have a presence in a particular country, doesn't mean you have a great network route to all the users there, and a good CDN tries to ensure that's the case.  See http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/dynamic-content/ if you want to learn more about it.

To answer your specific question, yes you can do it using IP forwarding behind the scenes.  Check out http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-to-a-new-ip-using-iptables/ if you need a how-to guide on how to do this.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Your answer did not immediately reply my issue, but it did help me to get a better solution, thanks.